# Microsoft-Forms tag needed

Tags: support, tags

While researching a problem, I was looking for a tag for Microsoft Forms, I didn't find one; there is a [forms] generic tag,  with 778 topics.  If I search without any tag term, for

https://superuser.com/search?q=microsoft+forms
and
https://superuser.com/search?q=%22Microsoft+forms%22

I found 25 total.  Using "MS Forms" and other variants yielded a few more.

I would suspect that if I waded through all topics with the[forms] tag, I'd likely find some more.

If this gets approved, I can improve the tags on the 25+ questions.

Comment: You only need 9 more rep, then you can create it.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll get to work on answering some questions.

Comment: @MarkStewart - Please don't submit anything but the highest quality answers.  Unless these questions are new, you will get a lot of eyes on your answers, which means they need to be high quality content.  A lot of new users make the mistake of submitting 10-15 answers in a short amount of time.

Comment: @ramhound Thanks for the warning.  I don't try to get points just to get points :)

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to the kind user that up-voted one of my previous answers.  I've edited a few posts to reference the [microsoft-forms] tag, and once someone approves them, I'll create the initial tag wiki for it.

Comment: Have not been impressed by your tag edit proposals so far.  They are incomplete and besides the tag, they don’t make the question answerable or easier to find.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, I haven't had time to wade through all the potential questions to re-tag; I'll focus a little harder.